# Regex test() method returning false for a valid regex having match

Tags: javascript, regex

When pattern is being tested in https://regex101.com/r/YbRw2h/1, it is displaying two matches.

```js
var patt = /\{panel:bgColor=#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})}(\r\n|\r|\n)?(.*?){panel}/gm

var str = `{panel:bgColor=#deebff}\nThis is info panel\n{panel}fkjfkfwkwfj\
    
                 {panel:bgColor=#deebff}\nThis is info panel\n{panel}`


console.log(patt.test(str)) //false
```

How to fix regex?

Comment: It should be ``var str = String.raw`{panel:bg`` etc...

Comment: @Thefourthbird Why?

Comment: @mplungjan If you want to display the 2 matches, you get this https://regex101.com/r/BNMqUq/1 But I think that the OP wants to match a newline instead of `\n` literally. Something like `{panel:bgColor=#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})}[^]*?{panel}` perhaps https://regex101.com/r/TFz7Ga/1

Comment: @Mahi Did that work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
{panel:bgColor=#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})}[^]*?{panel}
```

**Explanation**

- `{panel:bgColor=#` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}` Match 6 occurrences of A-F a-f or a digit 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}` Match 3 occurrences of A-F a-f or a digit 0-9
- `)` Close non capture group
- `}` Match literally
- `[^]*?` Match any char including newlines non greedy
- `{panel}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFz7Ga/1)